# Scale-independent error metric for data with many zeros

Tags: time-series, error, model-evaluation, measurement-error

I've been working on a time series forecasting model. I can't use a scale-dependent error measurement. And my target outputs also occasionally have zeros, meaning I can't use MAPE either. What is the best choice for me in this situation?

I've thought about adding some amount (for example, the mean) to all of the outputs (all non-negative) to make them all non-zeros and then use MAPE, but I'm not sure what would be an appropriate amount.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that you can’t use a scale-dependent error measurement?

Comment: thanks @Dave ! my target outputs are on different scales (think predicting prices for different products), so scale-dependent errors such as MAE won't be a good indicator of the model's performance.